# How to make one ajax request instead of multiple on endless scroll implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I load every next 10 publication to the feed, when user scrolls to the bottom. The problem is ajax sends multiple requests since this code detects multiple scroll-to-bottom events. How to make one ajax request instead of multiple, considering that user scroll further down?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {           

        $.ajax({
            url: '/more/',
            type:'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:2,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);          
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you want the function to fire only once? Or once every time they scroll to the bottom?

Comment: @user2085143 obviously every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use a lock to check if ajax is still in operation and don't make next ajax call till you receive data through ajax, after which you can free the lock.**

```
var lock = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {

if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {           

if(lock==true){
return;

}

lock = true;        

$.ajax({
            url: '/more/',
            type:'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:2,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);                              
            }
        }).always(function() {
            lock = false;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       alert("bottom!");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
    var jqXHR = $(document).data("jqXHR");
    if(jqXHR) {
      return;
    }
    jqXHR = $.ajax({
      url: '/more/',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: 2,
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      }
    });
    $(document).data("jqXHR", jqXHR);
    jqXHR.always(function(){
        $(document).removeData("jqXHR");
    });
  }
});
```